# How to make if condition for columns in excel with QlikView script

Tags: excel, qlikview

Here's the objective, I'm loading EXCEL files to QlikView, but I don't know their particular structure, all I need is if they got column, named 'Date'.
How can I make 'if condition' for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FieldNumber('field ' ,'TableName') , see [english QlikView Reference V11](http://community.qlikview.com/docs/DOC-1794) , p. 337. Alas the reference does not tell which value will be given if the field does not exist - therefore I tried and it's 0. Next point is to get the TableName - just name your excel 'TestTable' for the example.

```
if FieldNumber('Date','TestTable') > 0 then
  let echo = 'Date present';
ELSE
  let echo = 'Date not present';
```